# How can my 57.6 kbaud serial connection trasmit over 100 kbytes per second?

Tags: qt, serial-port, communication

I have an Arduino which dumps serial data continuously, and a Qt application reads the data on my computer.

I use `QSerialPort`, and I can count a much larger amount of bytes received as what `QSerialPort::baudRate()` indicates.

Interestingly, If I use a serial-to-USB Converter on my external device, the baudrate set on the external device corresponds to the rate I can read the data in the Qt application. In this mode, the Arduino just sends data over its USART to an serial-to-USB Converter, and it's seen as a virtual COM port on the PC.

However, if I use the "native USB" port on the Arduino Due, it is still detected as a virtual COM port and I can read from it with `QSerialPort` without any special settings, just by calling `open()` and `read()`. If I check the baudrate by calling `baudRate()`, I get 57600. However, by timing with `QTime` and counting the received bytes, I measure a much higher data rate than 57600 bits per second.

If I use a buffer of 20 bytes, I can manage around 100 kbyte/sec, with a buffer of 180 bytes I can receive at almost 1.4 Mbyte/sec.

I checked that the data is correctly received (and it's not just junk).

Is just `QSerialPort::baudRate()` broken, or did I miss something obvious?